# How to display json data returned from web service into ASP.net MVC 4 bootstrap table

Tags: json, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am designing web page which uses bootstrap and ASP.net MVC4 and IDE used is VS 2012. I have a web service that returns data in json format. Now I want to use that web servcie and display the json data into the bootstrap table.

Please let me know how can I archieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: here's a nice Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/13/

Answer (score 0):

You can provide JSON data source to Bootstrap table using the following bootstrapped table plugin on Github https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table